# Determining incomplete sections in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a JavaScript object with several properties:

```
{
  banking: {
    account_number: null,
    account_type: null,
    bank_name: null,
    debit_day: null
  },
  fitment: {
    date: null,
    terms: null
  },
  personal_info: {
    email: null,
    IDNumber: null,
    mobile: null,
    name: null,
    residential_address: null,
    surname: null,
    title: null,
    work_address: null,
    work_tel: null
  },
  vehicle: {
    brand: null,
    colour: null,
    model: null,
    registration: null,
    vin: null,
    year: null
  }
}
```

All top level properties and nested properties has default value of `null`.

I'm trying to figure out a way to categorize the properties into three groups, namely:

**empty**, **partial** and **complete**.

"**empty**" being a case that all values within a section are set as `null`.

"**partial**" being that some values within a section have been set (not all `null`)

"**complete**" being that no values within a section are set to `null`. All have values.

My first attempt was with utilizing the Underscore library with `_.some()`, however I can't seem to wrap my head around catering for all group scenarios.

Some help and guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: by categorize what do you mean? do you just want a separate array/object that returns each section category or you want to add a new key to each section where you save the category value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for `every` first, and then follow-up with `some`, or default to `empty`.

```js
const main = () => {
  const sectionStatus = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(sections).map(([section, data]) => [
      section,
      Object.entries(data).every(([id, value]) => value !== null)
        ? 'complete'
        : Object.entries(data).some(([id, value]) => value !== null)
          ? 'partial'
          : 'empty'
    ]));
  
  console.log(sectionStatus);
};

const sections = {
  banking: {
    account_number: '555',
    account_type: null,
    bank_name: null,
    debit_day: null
  },
  fitment: {
    date: new Date(),
    terms: 'foobar'
  },
  personal_info: {
    email: null,
    IDNumber: null,
    mobile: null,
    name: null,
    residential_address: null,
    surname: null,
    title: null,
    work_address: null,
    work_tel: null
  },
  vehicle: {
    brand: null,
    colour: null,
    model: null,
    registration: null,
    vin: null,
    year: null
  }
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Output

```json
{
  "banking": "partial",
  "fitment": "complete",
  "personal_info": "empty",
  "vehicle": "empty"
}
```

If you want to optimize this you can mark each field with a `1` (not `null`) or `0` (`null`) and reduce the values.

```js
const main = () => {
  const sectionStatus = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(sections).map(([section, data]) => { 
      const flags = Object.values(data).map((v) => v !== null ? 1 : 0);
      const state = flags.reduce((a, b) => a & b, 1) === 1 // or (a * b)
        ? 'complete'
        : flags.reduce((a, b) => a | b, 0) === 1 // or (a + b) > 0
          ? 'partial'
          : 'empty';
      return [section, state];
    }, []));
  
  console.log(sectionStatus);
};

const sections = {
  banking: {
    account_number: '555',
    account_type: null,
    bank_name: null,
    debit_day: null
  },
  fitment: {
    date: new Date(),
    terms: 'foobar'
  },
  personal_info: {
    email: null,
    IDNumber: null,
    mobile: null,
    name: null,
    residential_address: null,
    surname: null,
    title: null,
    work_address: null,
    work_tel: null
  },
  vehicle: {
    brand: null,
    colour: null,
    model: null,
    registration: null,
    vin: null,
    year: null
  }
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Works exactly as intended. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can further decompose this problem by also using `_.groupBy`. First, a function just to determine the category of a single section:

```js
function category(section) {
    return _.every(section, _.isNull) ? 'empty' :
           _.some(section, _.isNull) ? 'partial' : 'complete';
}
```

Then, combine this with `_.groupBy` to create an array of original objects for each category:

```js
_.groupBy(sections, category)
```

Putting it all together:

```js
var sections = {
  banking: {
    account_number: null,
    account_type: null,
    bank_name: null,
    debit_day: null
  },
  fitment: {
    date: null,
    terms: null
  },
  personal_info: {
    email: null,
    IDNumber: null,
    mobile: null,
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    residential_address: null,
    surname: null,
    title: null,
    work_address: null,
    work_tel: null
  },
  vehicle: {
    brand: null,
    colour: null,
    model: null,
    registration: null,
    vin: null,
    year: null
  }
};

function category(section) {
    return _.every(section, _.isNull) ? 'empty' :
           _.some(section, _.isNull) ? 'partial' : 'complete';
}

console.log(_.groupBy(sections, category));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```